# `settings.prc = false` leads to singular matrix

Tags: asymptote

I have a very silly asymptote file that I cannot seem to render properly.

```
settings.prc = false;
import three;
draw(unitsphere);
```

I am compiling with `asy test.asy -outformat pdf`, but my output is

```
/usr/share/asymptote/three.asy: 2905.13: Singular matrix
```

Removing `settings.prc = false;` seems to let it compile but I cannot view it with my pdf viewer (zathura, and all I see is a blank page), nor do I want to embed PRC data into my PDFs.

Comment: Could you try to add `size(5cm);` ? If you have error compilation, please precise Asymptote version, OS...

Comment: It is reproducible with `size(5cm);`, but `settings.render = 0;` will let it render normally and I can view it in PDF. It seems as if the only way to flatten images is setting render=0.

Comment: In my case I have no problem with `settings.render=4`. You have an installation problem. Could you precise OS, asymptote version (from your package manager), Texlive or not Texlive asymptote version (in my opinion in view of the directory it is not a Texlive version) and the output of `asy -version`. Perhaps you have a Texlive version and a package manager version ? What happens with `asy -V test.asy` (and `settings.render=4`) `-V` is the interactive OpenGL renderer ?